# Making a site with 3 div with center content and 2 "buffers" to fill the reminig horizontal space

Tags: css, css-float, html, centering

I am making a css site and I want to look like that:
3 vertical divs. **LEFT CENTER RIGHT**. In the **center** div is the site content, and I want the **left** and **right** div to fill the space between the center and the browser borders.

Here is my code.

```
    #container
{
 width:100%;
 background-color:#000;
}
.center
{
 width:1000px;
 height:400px;
 background-color:#F90;
 margin: 0px auto;
 overflow: auto;
}
.spacer-left
{ 
 width:100%;
 height:400px;
 background-color:#F90;
 float:left;
}
.spacer-right
{ width:100%;
 height:400px;
 background-color:#F90;
}
```

And here is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
<div id="container">
<div class="spacer-left"></div>
<div class="center" style="background-color:#F30;"></div>
<div class="spacer-right"></div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I've try with 2 divs and there was no problem. The left with float:left and width in pixels and right one with 100% width without float. It worked. But how to make it with 3 divs. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for the help Sebastian but I figured out other way.
This is how the code looks now and it works.

```
#container
{
    width:1000px;
    background-color:#000;
    margin:0 auto;
}
.center
{
    width:100%;
    height:400px;
    background-color:#F90;
    margin: 0px auto;
    overflow: auto;
}
.spacer
{   
    width:50%;
    height:400px;
    background-color:#F90;
    float:left;
}
.head_warp
{
    width:100%;
    display:block;
    height:400px;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0;
    position:absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    text-align:center;
    z-index:-9999;
}
```

and the HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
<div class="head_warp">
<div class="spacer"></div>
<div class="spacer" style="background-color:#F06"></div>
</div>
<div id="container">
<div class="center" style="background-color:#F30;"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you for the help one again. I will write here again if there is a problem with my solution.

Comment: great Victor, you should upvote and accept answers if the problem is solved.

Comment: How to do that because I am not familiar with the system here.

Answer (score 0):

Update: a different alternative to the answer below, using three divs and z-index.

http://jsfiddle.net/SebastianPataneMasuelli/mzvB4/1/

if you are trying to make a site with the content in the center div, you can replicate that layout using simply:

```
<body>
  <div class="center">center</div>
</body>
```

with the css:

```
html {height: 100%;   }
.center { width:750px; margin: 30px auto; height: 100%; }
```

play with it here: http://jsfiddle.net/SebastianPataneMasuelli/mzvB4/

from the class names `.spacer_left` and `.spacer_right` i'm assuming that those divs are empty spacers and not necessary.

this is a good resource for base css layouts: http://www.csseasy.com/

Comment: I want to put background images in the .spacer_left and .spacer_right thats why I want it that way.

Comment: you can put a background on the body tag itself, since the content width has a fixed width, you can use a single image for both background and give it a center background attachment.

Comment: Thank you for the advice but I know that. I want the background repeating x so to fill the space whatevere the resolution of the user screen.

Comment: ok, check the updated version above, it gives you a left and right background div.